# Difference Between Number of CPEs and Number of hosts

Tags: router, wireless, dhcp, ieee-802.11

I have to extend the wifi range by using two wireless routers.First I will have to configure the **DHCP** settings in my primary router.But its setting mentions number of **CPEs** instead of **Hosts**.Do they mean the same?

Comment: CPE means Customer Placed Equipment and a term normally used by an ISP about it's network equipment placed at a customer. Hosts are normally referred to as the users/servers etc. connected to a network.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CPE stand for [`Customer Premise Equipment`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer-premises_equipment)

It is mainly used in the context of a connection provided by an ISP to a customer site. The CPE is the router put on the customer site on which the line is connected. It's the entry point to the customer network.

In your case, it seems to be used in a different way, and actually seems to refer to the hosts, but it's an unusual usage.

Comment: Man in all those years and i was sure it meant placed equipment. I'm glad i learned something. I do like provided better though, but i guess it's not very strict. :-)